# HEAPSPACE ERROR: cannot figure out what is causing the error

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm, jvisualvm

Would anyone mind having a look at these bits of code and see if there is a memory leak in them, it isn't going to be overly large but my program keeps crashing after a while of running and I don't know how to use viualvm even though I have been reading up on it for several days now and haven't the slightest idea what I am looking for in the heap dumps and so on. thanks for your help,
ps I know I have posted far to muchg code but i dont know what else to do so that you can hopefully see where the problem arises for me. If it helps I can email you the full program to take a look at. Thanks very much for any help you can give.

```
  public class extraScreenPanel {

    static JPanel screenPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 

    public static JPanel extraScreenPanel(int dispNum) 
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("" + dispNum + "");
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        label.setVerticalAlignment( SwingConstants.TOP );
        screenPanel = imgDisp(dispNum);
        label.setForeground(Color.white);
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 200));
        screenPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END );

        return screenPanel;
    }



    public static JPanel imgDisp(int picNum) {  
        String ref = "C:/PiPhotoPic/pic16.jpg";;
        BufferedImage loadImg = loadImage(ref);  
        JImagePanel panel = new JImagePanel(loadImg, 0, 0);  
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        return panel;
    }  


    public static class JImagePanel extends JPanel{  
        private BufferedImage image;  
        int x, y;  
       public JImagePanel(BufferedImage image, int x, int y) {  
            super();  
            this.image = image;  
            this.x = x;  
            this.y = y;  
        }  
        @Override  
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
           super.paintComponent(g);  
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);  
       }  
    }  


    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String ref) {  
            BufferedImage bimg = null;  
            try {  

              bimg = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(ref));  
         } catch (Exception e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         } 
         BufferedImage bimg2 = resize(bimg,800,600);//set these to the resolution of extra screens
         return bimg2;  
     }  


     public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {  
        int w = img.getWidth();  
        int h = img.getHeight();  
        BufferedImage dimg = dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());  
        Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);  
        g.dispose();  
        return dimg;  
    }  


}
```

Another part of the method

```
public class piPhoto
{
    static int mostRecent = 0;
    static int dispNum = 0;
    static int lastDisp = 0;
    static JPanel picPanel = imgDisp.imgDisp(dispNum);
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pi Photography");
    static JPanel cornerPanel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel currentNumPanel = currentNumDisp.currentNumDisp(dispNum);
    static JPanel printPanel = printOptions.printOptions();
    static JPanel buttonPanel = updateButtonPanel.updateButtonPanel(mostRecent);
    static JPanel screen1Panel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel screen2Panel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel screen3Panel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel screen4Panel = new JPanel();
    static JPanel screenPanel12 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel screenPanel123 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel screenPanel1234 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel screensPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel deskScreen = new JPanel();
    static JPanel wholePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JPanel wholePanel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());




    public static void launchPiPhoto()
    {
        launchNC4.launch();

        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440, 200));
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1120, 200));
        cornerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        screen1Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        screen2Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        screen3Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        screen4Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        screensPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3200,600));
        deskScreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        wholePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(4640,900));
        wholePanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5440,900));
        cornerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cornerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        picPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1120, 620));


        //Menu Panel Set-up
        cornerPanel.add(currentNumPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(cornerPanel);
        menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440, 840));
        menuPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        menuPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        menuPanel.add(picPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        menuPanel.add(printPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        screen1Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 3);
        screen2Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 2);
        screen3Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 1);
        screen4Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent);
        screenPanel12.add(screen1Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel12.add(screen2Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screenPanel123.add(screenPanel12, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel123.add(screen3Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screenPanel1234.add(screenPanel123, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel1234.add(screen4Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screensPanel.add(screenPanel1234, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        deskScreen = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(dispNum);

        wholePanel.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        wholePanel.add(screensPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        wholePanel2.add(wholePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        wholePanel2.add(deskScreen, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        frame.add(wholePanel2);

        //Frame set-up and Initializing
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        newImageRecieved.runCheck();
    }

    public static void repaintButtonPanel()
    {
        bottomPanel.removeAll();
        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440, 200));
        buttonPanel = updateButtonPanel.updateButtonPanel(mostRecent);
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1120, 200));
        cornerPanel.add(currentNumPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(cornerPanel);
        menuPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.validate();
    }

        public static void repaintScreens()
    {
        wholePanel.remove(screensPanel);
        screen1Panel.removeAll();
        screen1Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent);
        screen2Panel.removeAll();
        screen2Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 1);
        screen3Panel.removeAll();
        screen3Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 2);
        screen4Panel.removeAll();
        screen4Panel = extraScreenPanel.extraScreenPanel(piPhoto.mostRecent - 3);
        screenPanel12.add(screen1Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel12.add(screen2Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screenPanel123.add(screenPanel12, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel123.add(screen3Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screenPanel1234.add(screenPanel123, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        screenPanel1234.add(screen4Panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        screensPanel.add(screenPanel1234, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        wholePanel.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        wholePanel.add(screensPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.validate();
    }



}
```

the part that checks to see if new images are added to the file yet

```
    public class newImageRecieved {
static int count = 0;

public static void runCheck()
{
     int delay = 500;
     ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            newImageRecieved(piPhoto.mostRecent+1);
        }
     };
     new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}

    public static void newImageRecieved(int picNum)
    {

            String url[] = new String[5000];
            String part1;
        url[0] = "C:/PiPhotoPic/pic16.jpg";
        for(Integer i=1;i<5000;i++){
            if(i<10){part1 = "C:/temp/new0000000";}
            else if(i<100){part1 = "C:/temp/new000000";}
            else if(i<1000){part1 = "C:/temp/new00000";}
            else {part1 = "C:/temp/new00000";}
            String num = Integer.toString(i);
            url[i]= part1 + num + ".jpg";
        }
        if(picNum<0){picNum=0;}
        String ref = url[picNum];
            piPhoto.frame.validate();
            boolean exists = (new File(ref)).exists();
            if(exists == true)
            {
                while (exists == true) 
                {
                    piPhoto.updateMostRecent(picNum);
                    ref = url[picNum + 1];
                    picNum = picNum + 1;
                    exists = (new File(ref)).exists();

                }

                piPhoto.updateMostRecent(picNum-1);
                piPhoto.repaintButtonPanel();
                piPhoto.repaintScreens();
                count=0;
            }
        //  }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: With the current setup I have for the imagepanel would anyone be able to help me out in writing a setImage method so as I can just change the image rather than having to recreate the wholepanel each time, I think this or something about the JImagePanel method is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it today. Turns out I didnt remove the image panels from the old method, aso that when i  was repainting them I was painting over the old ones and the old ones were still there. So I just needed to add in removeAll() for all the panels that were being updated and the program ran fine without heapstack errors.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a memory profiler such as [YourKit](http://yourkit.com)

Comment: PS - I tried all of the current open source and commercial profilers about 4 weeks ago and found YourKit to be the best, but there are others out there too.  YourKit has a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating an array of 5000 strings and start fill up most of them.

Comment: would this take up alot of memory?
Also will the array of Strings be GC'd oncethe scope containng it is closed? do statics disappear the same a non-static variables?

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee when the GC will act.  Even if you ask the GC explicitly to run "now", that's only a request.  Garbage Collection will happen when the JVM thinks it is time to collect.

Comment: I was meaning when the method that creates a static variable ends, will the static variable be available for GC or does it stay for the lenght of the program as it is a static variable?

Comment: @pie154: under normal circumstances, objects that are reachable from a static variable will not be garbage collected.

Comment: I removed the vast number of strings, but this only prolonged the lentgh of time it took to get the error. Ttried to look through a heap dump, and there are alot of bytes, most of which have something to do with rasters, this is something to do with iamges right? most of them link to the imagepanel method, is it likely there is something wrong with the way it works or that I replace images using it?